# Invariance of commutator relations under change of basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, coordinate-systems, commutator

Consider the following:

Let for operators $\hat A$ and $\hat B$ the following commutation relation holds:

$$[\hat A,\hat B]=\hat C \tag{1}$$

and now we know that this relation holds,

$$[\hat A',\hat B']=\hat C' \tag{2}$$

where,

$$\hat A'=T_{_{X\leftarrow Y}}A$$

$$\hat B'=T_{_{X\leftarrow Y}}B$$

$$\hat C'=T_{_{X\leftarrow Y}}C$$

(Since commutation relations do not depend on a change of basis )

Now,
it's easy to prove this for a Unitary transformation $U$ (which is nothing but a change of basis) as follows:

$$[\hat A',\hat B']=\hat A'\hat B'-\hat B'\hat A'=UAU^{\dagger}UBU^{\dagger}-UBU^{\dagger}UAU^{\dagger}=U(AB-BA)U^{\dagger}=UCU^{\dagger}=C'$$

where now, (I think this is where the problem is$^1$ )

$$\hat A'=UAU^{\dagger}$$

$$\hat B'=UBU^{\dagger}$$

$$\hat C'=UCU^{\dagger}$$

*Here U (which is nothing but a transformation/transition matrix) is getting applied on both ends since A is an operator here on a ket of Hilbert space as opposed to the transition matrix which just gets pre-multiplied.$^{2}$*

When I try to prove $(2)$ from $(1)$ for my previous case involving transition matrix this happens;

$$[\hat A',\hat B']=\hat A'\hat B'-\hat B'\hat A'=T_{_{X\leftarrow Y}}AT_{_{X\leftarrow Y}}B-T_{_{X\leftarrow Y}}B T_{_{X\leftarrow Y}}A$$

I am stuck here and I think the resolution is related to  $^{1}$ and  $^{2}$

I think we should be able to prove the above relation or does change of basis (not changing commutator relations) only work for Hilbert spaces where $T$ (transformation matrices which are always unitary for orthonormal basis change for Hilbert space) on an operator behave as U()U^{\dagger} and not for a general change of basis like I tried
above for vector spaces which are .....um...non-Hilbert?

Comment: That's not how a change of basis work on operators.

Comment: Yes @fqq is correct. Even for general basis change $A'=TAT^{-1}$ and not what you wrote as the relations.

Comment: Incidentally, it's not true that changes of basis are necessarily unitary in Hilbert spaces. They have no a priori relation to the scalar product structure.

Comment: Why? An operator is a square matrix and for any matrix, a change basis is simply a pre-multiplication with a transition matrix.

Comment: @sslucifer Yes for an operator it is the equation that you have written but an operator is just a square matrix and from linear algebra, any change of basis for a matrix is what I wrote above.  Isn't it?

Comment: @Lost pre multiplication works on vectors, like $|v'\rangle=T|v\rangle$. You can derive for an operator that, this pre multiplication is not true.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis

Comment: @fqq It can be easily proved that for a complete and orthonormal ordered basis change a transformation is *always* unitary.

Comment: @sslucifer It works for matrices, right? While studying that in Linear Algebra, nobody told me that those matrices have to be vectors for this relation to hold.

Comment: @Lost of course, you added "orthonormal".

Comment: @fqq yes yes. But the commutator relations anyways hold even for non-orthonormal basis change whose transformations are non-unitary (ryt?). But thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Lost A question being valid and helpful to others is only a necessary condition for the post to not be closed; it's not a sufficient condition. Also incorrect content is not a closure reason.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Then what can I improve in my question that might've caused a closure vote?

Comment: It reads kind of like a check my work question.

Comment: @Lost I'm not sure what you mean. I didn't say anything about reputation.

Comment: I just meant that I couldn't even imagine that this would read like a check my work question

Comment: This is disappointing.

Comment: @Lost It's only one vote. One vote by itself means nothing. It happens all of the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Summing over repeated indices, entries in the original commutator relation satisfy $C_{ij}=A_{ik}B_{kj}-A_{kj}B_{ik}$. The most general linear transformation of operators is $A^\prime_{ij}=X_{ijmn}A_{mn}$, and you're welcome to determine the condition on $X$ equivalent to $X_{ijmn}(A_{mr}B_{rn}-A_{rn}B_{mr})=A_{ik}B_{kj}-A_{kj}B_{ik}$. But as @fqq and @sslucifer note, if we want every vector to transform viz. $v^\prime=Tv$ we need $TAv=A^\prime v^\prime=A^\prime Tv$, so $A^\prime=TAT^{-1}$. (The condition $T^{-1}=T^\dagger$ preserves the inner product, but not all bases of interest are orthonormal.) This is the case $X_{ijmn}=T_{im}(T^{-1})_{nj}$, which you can verify works out. So depending on your perspective, you can see this transformation as multiplying $A$ by either one or two factors.

Comment: @Lost this is a very good answer. The reason why $TAv=A'v'$ is because $Av$ is also a vector belonging to same vector space which is true for any Hilbert space. So the vector $Av$ must be transformed by the same relation.